# read.csv.sql inserts all rows despite the WHERE clause in its SQL clause

Tags: r, sqlite, sqldf, read.csv

I use the following (pseudo) code to import huge CSV files in R when only a rather small portion of the data in the file has to be treated/imported and other rows should simply be ignored. I don't put data in-memory but in a SQLite database which is created by the program.

```
library(sqldf)
suppressWarnings(read.csv.sql(
    file = input_file_path,
    sql = "
       create table mytable as 
       select
           . . .
       from
           file
       where
           . . .
      ",
    header = FALSE,
    sep = "|",
    eol = "\n",
    `field.types` = list( . . . )
    dbname = sqlite_db_path,
    drv = "SQLite"
))
```

If I understand the documentation of `read.csv.sql` correctly, the `WHERE` clause in the `CREATE TABLE` statement above, guarantees that only rows satisfying the condition of the WHERE clause will be inserted in the created table `mytable`. However, last night during a test I found somewhat a strange behaviour in my program. I had to import a big CSV file (more than 100 000 000 rows), but only a set of 10 000 rows was the target and all other rows had to be ignored. The above program did the job and at the end, the created table `mytable` indicated in the code above, had only 10 000 rows as expected which proves that the condition in the `WHERE` clause was taken into account. However, when I checked the size of the created SQLite database, it was abnormally huge (more than 25 GB). That cannot possibly be the size of 10 000 rows.

Therefore, I'm confused. What happened during the import process? Why the SQLite database file became so huge depsite the fact that only 10 000 rows were inserted in `mytable` and everything else was ignored? Is this the normal behaviour or it's me who is not using correctly `read.csV.sql`?

Comment: It first uses `dbWriteTable` to write the file to the database.  Then it operates on that.  You co consider using grep/findstr/xsv to extract out the rows of interest piping that direclty into R.  `read.table(pipe("grep ..."), sep = ",")` or in Windows `findstr` or the `xsv` or other csv utility and use that instead of grep.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. So long as the data goes directly into the database and not in-memory (RAM) that doesn't bother me, I asked the question because I was curious and I couldn't explain what was actually happening during the import. Therefore, this is the normal behaviour. Thank you very much for your time and your help. I'm going to rewrite your comment down there and accept it as the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @G. Grothendieck for his clarification :

It first uses dbWriteTable to write the file to the database. Then it operates on that. You co consider using grep/findstr/xsv to extract out the rows of interest piping that direclty into R. read.table(pipe("grep ..."), sep = ",") or in Windows findstr or the xsv or other csv utility and use that instead of grep. –

Answer (score 0):

edit: this is an elaboration on the suggestions @G.Grothendieck makes in the comment-section above.

--

I do not have experience with `read.csv.sql`, but you might want to take a look at importing the output from a shell-command. This way, you preprocess the csv, and only import the result.

For eaxmple, `data.table::fread(cmd = 'findstr "^[^#]" test.csv', sep = "\n", header = FALSE)` imports all lines from the csv `test.csv` that do not start with a `#`-character.

So it import the output from the (windows) command: `findstr "^[^#]" test.csv` to a data.table, using all the power of `data.table::fread()` and it's arguments. This will also work on *nix-environments, but you'll have to use the appropriate shell-commands (like `grep`).

Note that an approach like this might work very well (and fast!), but it makes it impossible to swap your code around on multiple operating systems.

Comment: xsv is available on all systems that R is so that would allow the same code to work on all systems provided xsv is downloaded.  Also it understands csv so you will still get the header line.  csvtk is another similar utility.  If you add verbose=TRUE to the read.csv.sql command then it will show what RSQLite commands it is invoking.